# How to set cell fit the page automatically in itext?

Tags: itext

I create a table and a cell by itext, and this cell to add a image, but the image is very large, so the cell is split in new page. how can I set the cell fit the page, I used jar itextpdf5.5.6.jar, and I can not find the method about cell or table do not split or can fit the page automatically.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but don't download jar files. Use Maven and let it do the heavy lifting for you. Also, iText 5 is now at version 5.5.10.

Comment: Please show your current pivotal code ([edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42503697/edit) your question to add it there), so people here can improve it.